# AES PBE Encrypt in Java / Decrypt in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, cryptography, encryption

Using the Bouncy Castle PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC algo to encrypt string data in Java.  Having a hard time getting it decrypted in ruby.  I've seen a handful of examples of similar operations but none where the java PBEKeySpect is salted (not sure of course if that's the issue).  For some context here's the Java code;

```
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC", 
            org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);

    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("password".toCharArray(), 
            "8 bytes!", 1024, 128);

    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal("hello world".getBytes());
```

This runs without issue.  We however have not discovered the magic sequence to decrypting it on the Ruby side. If anyone would be willing to share examples of how to decrypt this in ruby (1.9.3) it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Below is the decryption code in ruby that is currently not working.

```
d = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-128-CBC")
d.decrypt
key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac_sha1("password", "8 bytes!", 1024, d.key_len)
d.key = key
d.iv = iv.scan(/../).map{|b|b.hex}.pack('c*')
data = enc.scan(/../).map{|b|b.hex}.pack('c*')
d.update(data) << d.final
```

This ruby code worked when the Java side is implementing the `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` algorithm (obviously) but for reasons that I can't exactly elaborate on, we can no longer use that implementation (hence `PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC`).

Comment: Why not use JRuby? Then you can use the same exact package for decryption.

Comment: That would be nice, but this code is running on Android (api level 8) - plus we don't have the freedom to use jruby on the server side where decryption occurs.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. I can understand frustration with something that simply fails without indication, but you might find people more willing to post answers if you show some Ruby code. Besides, it would help Ruby noobs like me that do know cryptography.

Comment: Using `getBytes()` can cause problems.  You need to specify exactly which encoding you are using, at both ends.  Something like, `getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Comment: @rossum nowadays I prefer Charset.forName("UTF-8") as it does away with the checked exception (which is never going to be thrown in a Java SE compliant runtime anyway; UTF-8 is a required character encoding).

Comment: @owlstead Yes, excellent point - I've updated the post to include the non-functioning Ruby code.  Also, thank you both for the guidance on character encoding.

Comment: I wonder if `"PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC"` uses PBKDF2 underneath, it's more likely to be PBKDF1 with a different hash method. Have you compared the generated key bytes between the implementations? If they are different, I may have a solutation for you.

Comment: @owlstead Yep, the generated key bytes differ between the two algorithms.  I would love to hear that possible solution!

Comment: do you know what BC standars for at the end ?

Comment: No, but I can find out (in the end, I could ask David @ the bouncy castle mailing list).

Comment: You are using PBKDF2 *with SHA-1* in your Ruby. In Java, it's not clear exactly what you are using, but whatever it is, it's *SHA-256,* not SHA-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there goes. You might have to marshall some parameters to fit though:

```
/**
 * Copied shamelessly from org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator,
 * changed only the hash algorithm.
 * All rights reserved by Bouncy Castle, see their MIT-like permissive license.
 * @author maartenb
 *
 */
public class PKCS5S2_SHA256_ParametersGenerator
    extends PBEParametersGenerator
{

    // NOTE this is the only actual change from PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator
    private Mac    hMac = new HMac(new SHA256Digest());

    /**
     * construct a PKCS5 Scheme 2 Parameters generator.
     */
    public PKCS5S2_SHA256_ParametersGenerator()
    {
    }

    private void F(
        byte[]  P,
        byte[]  S,
        int     c,
        byte[]  iBuf,
        byte[]  out,
        int     outOff)
    {
        byte[]              state = new byte[hMac.getMacSize()];
        CipherParameters    param = new KeyParameter(P);

        hMac.init(param);

        if (S != null)
        {
            hMac.update(S, 0, S.length);
        }

        hMac.update(iBuf, 0, iBuf.length);

        hMac.doFinal(state, 0);

        System.arraycopy(state, 0, out, outOff, state.length);

        if (c == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("iteration count must be at least 1.");
        }

        for (int count = 1; count < c; count++)
        {
            hMac.init(param);
            hMac.update(state, 0, state.length);
            hMac.doFinal(state, 0);

            for (int j = 0; j != state.length; j++)
            {
                out[outOff + j] ^= state[j];
            }
        }
    }


    private void intToOctet(
        byte[]  buf,
        int     i)
    {
        buf[0] = (byte)(i >>> 24);
        buf[1] = (byte)(i >>> 16);
        buf[2] = (byte)(i >>> 8);
        buf[3] = (byte)i;
    }

    private byte[] generateDerivedKey(
        int dkLen)
    {
        int     hLen = hMac.getMacSize();
        int     l = (dkLen + hLen - 1) / hLen;
        byte[]  iBuf = new byte[4];
        byte[]  out = new byte[l * hLen];

        for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++)
        {
            intToOctet(iBuf, i);

            F(password, salt, iterationCount, iBuf, out, (i - 1) * hLen);
        }

        return out;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a key parameter derived from the password, salt, and iteration
     * count we are currently initialised with.
     *
     * @param keySize the size of the key we want (in bits)
     * @return a KeyParameter object.
     */
    public CipherParameters generateDerivedParameters(
        int keySize)
    {
        keySize = keySize / 8;

        byte[]  dKey = generateDerivedKey(keySize);

        return new KeyParameter(dKey, 0, keySize);
    }

    /**
     * Generate a key with initialisation vector parameter derived from
     * the password, salt, and iteration count we are currently initialised
     * with.
     *
     * @param keySize the size of the key we want (in bits)
     * @param ivSize the size of the iv we want (in bits)
     * @return a ParametersWithIV object.
     */
    public CipherParameters generateDerivedParameters(
        int     keySize,
        int     ivSize)
    {
        keySize = keySize / 8;
        ivSize = ivSize / 8;

        byte[]  dKey = generateDerivedKey(keySize + ivSize);

        return new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(dKey, 0, keySize), dKey, keySize, ivSize);
    }

    /**
     * Generate a key parameter for use with a MAC derived from the password,
     * salt, and iteration count we are currently initialised with.
     *
     * @param keySize the size of the key we want (in bits)
     * @return a KeyParameter object.
     */
    public CipherParameters generateDerivedMacParameters(
        int keySize)
    {
        return generateDerivedParameters(keySize);
    }
}
```

Oh, and add Bouncy to your path of course...these are the required import statements:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.Mac;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.PBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA256Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.macs.HMac;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
```

[EDIT] example usage

```
        int iterations = 1000; // minimum
        int keySize = 256; // maximum
        final byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        SecureRandom rng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        rng.nextBytes(salt);
        char[] password = new char[] { 'o', 'w', 'l', 's', 't', 'e', 'a', 'd' };

        // S2 *is* PBKDF2, but the default used only HMAC(SHA-1)
        final PKCS5S2_SHA256_ParametersGenerator gen = new PKCS5S2_SHA256_ParametersGenerator();

        // lets not use String, as we cannot destroy strings, BC to the rescue!
        final byte[] pwBytes = Strings.toUTF8ByteArray(password);

        gen.init(pwBytes, salt, iterations);

        final KeyParameter params1 = (KeyParameter) gen.generateDerivedMacParameters(keySize);

        // use for/next loop for older Java versions, destroy password information in memory
        Arrays.fill(pwBytes, 0, pwBytes.length, (byte) 0);
        Arrays.fill(password, 0, password.length, ' ');
        final KeyParameter keyParam = params1;
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyParam.getKey().clone(), "AES");
```

[EDIT] forgot to include the license, even if I pointed to it, sorry about the legalize:

Copyright (c) 2000 - 2011 The Legion Of The Bouncy Castle (http://www.bouncycastle.org)

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: Do you need plumbing with that, or can you create some sort of solution out of this yourself?

Comment: sorry about the late response - yeah, I spent a good amount of time on Sat. trying to integrate that code to no avail - if you have any insight I would surely appreciate it.