# PKCS5 or Password Based Encryption (PBE) in JAVA

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, pkcs#5

I want to write a password based encryption and decryption in Java!

It means that I have a `K (Password)` and `P (plain Text)` and create such an `E (encrypted Text)` that I can then decrypt that `E` with my first `K`.

As I mentioned from the questions and their answers in StackOverflow like [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526479/aes-pbe-encrypt-in-java-decrypt-in-ruby) and [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption) my solution is PKCS5 but they firstly generate `K1` from `K` and then encode that `K1` and generate `K2` from `K1`. and then encrypt `P` and decrypt `E` with that `K2`.

But It's not what I want. Each time you generate `K2` from `K`, the new `K2` differs from last `K2` so you can't decrypt with a new `K2` an encrypted text that encrypted with previous `K2`.

How can I code this scenario in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. Given the same password and salt (and iteration count, but that is often fixed in advance) you will get the same `K1` and `K2`. You can store the salt with your ciphertext, so that you can generate the same `K1` and `K2` for decryption.

The `K2` key encode/decode trick is only required because of a Java API mistake. The PBKDF2 implementation of Java generates a key for which the algorithm is set to `"PBE..."`. That key is not necessarily accepted for a normal AES `Cipher`. Therefore a "new" key is generated using the same key bytes, but with a different algorithm name (`"AES"`). Now if you could simply choose the algorithm name and key size during generation, the encoding/decoding would not be necessary. But in the end, K1 and K2 are effectively the same key.